# Problem while playing video in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 recently. Now I am facing a problem while playing video. While Um watching a video, the sound is continuous but the video is not, its appearing taking about one minute pause. So, the motion isn't flawless. How can I fix this problem??

Comment: Which app are you using to display the video? What happens when you launch a known good video such as https://archive.org/details/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space_1959 ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the video is lagging a minute after sound. Not sure you are what player you are using. Here is a simple fix for VLC(auuming you are using VLC). [`http://lifehacker.com/5910943/fix-out-of-sync-audio-in-vlc-with-a-keyboard-shortcut`](http://lifehacker.com/5910943/fix-out-of-sync-audio-in-vlc-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)